# What is the best way to connect remotely to a Mac?

Tags: macos, controls, desktop

I'm trying to remotely control a Macintosh computer.  I know that in the Windows world, you can use Remote Desktop to connect from one Windows computer to another Windows computer.  This works relatively well.

I know that you can use a VNC server but this isn't always the most secure or give the best performance.  Are there other options available for remotely connecting to a Mac?

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to connect from one (Leopard) Mac to another, you can use the built-in Screen Sharing functionality; turn the server on from the Sharing System Preferences pane, and either use the network browser (on a LAN) or just open a vnc:// URL.

If you're trying to manage a bunch of Macs, try Apple's [Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) (ARD) software; it's sold in 10- and unlimited-client versions, so if you've got fewer than 5 or so Macs it's probably not worth the money.  The client bits for ARD are part of OS X.  Screen Sharing and ARD use the same protocol, which includes some Apple-proprietary extensions to VNC which do encryption (either of all data, or of just keystroke/password info) and support adaptive JPEG compression, which gives you decent-enough performance (usable, but nothing like RDP or NX unfortunately).

If you need something cross-platform, check out [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx) (which will punch through firewalls and so forth).

Answer (score 6):

In some situations [Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) is a good solution.  Not so much for day-to-day admin, but great for remote tech support.

If you need the solution to be cross-platform (ie, controlling an OS X box from Windows) then VNC is the obvious choice.  I've had much better luck with the free [Vine VNC Server](http://www.redstonesoftware.com/products/vine_server) than with Apple's built in one.  As for viewers, [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) on OS X or [Tight VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) on Windows are good solutions.

As others have said, for security firewall VNC and then use an SSH tunnel.  There's lots of ways to do that, and the exact details depends on OS, firewall, network, etc.  One method of creating an SSH tunnel for VNC is described [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050429153115383).

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) has AES encryption. Another good way is to just enable SSH in sharing and use shell access to perform tasks without interrupting the user.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

^That's your best solution.

If you go into the Settings panel, you can find a variety of other remote access options including SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VNC](http://www.macminicolo.net/Mac_VNC_tutor.html) which is built into Tiger.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, VNC is good, but what about Apple's Remote Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a free, secure solution: I would recommend using any of a number of VNC servers that are available, blocking the ports that VNC uses to communicate, and then using SSH tunneling to connect.  This way, ssh is encrypting everything, and you can still rely on free, open source (?), and cross platform standards for controlling the Desktop remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix, the people behind pc anywhere and the windows remote desktop have a hosted app called "Go to my pc" https://www.gotomypc.com/

I've heard people says it good.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like RHUB's service for remote access and collaboration. It's an appliance that's easy to use and very secure. The device works from behind your firewall (instead of outside of it).

Answer (score 0):

if you need low bandwidth or cross platform there's RDP server for mac that also offers there own iRapp protocol

from their site:

> http://www.coderebel.com/2013/11/08/irapp-mac-client-available-download
>
> Lowest supported speed: 512 kbit/s (64 KB/s) for iRAPP protocol
>
> By adjusting the image quality you are able to make iRAPP work on
>   lower bandwidth connections as recommended above.
>
> iRapp TS (Mac Terminal Server) allows multiple users to connect one
>   Mac simultaneously

Comment: Sorry to report that CodeRebel went bankrupt although the website is still up as of this writing. https://www.coderebel.com/licensing/irapp/purchase/personal/